# How to use adb to get device contents list (of files and directories) onto a Windows system

Tags: android, windows, adb

How can I use adb.exe to create a file on my Windows development system of all directories and files on the android device.

So far, attempts to use something like

```
dev:/ $ ls -R > (someoutputpathorfile)
```

results in a message “Read-only file system” or “No such file or directory”.

Comment: I think you are searching for a command like `adb shell ls -R / > list.txt`. the important part is that you have to write everything in one command you execute in Windows. Note that the adb she'll used don't has permissions to list or read data in `/data/data` so the part will always be missing.